# Update siteurl and home in multisite subsites to https

Tags: multisite, options, https, site-url

I want rewrite the siteurl and home options on multisite subsites.

In `wp-admin/option.php` this is it:

```
if ( !is_multisite() ) {
    if ( !defined( 'WP_SITEURL' ) )
        $whitelist_options['general'][] = 'siteurl';
    if ( !defined( 'WP_HOME' ) )
        $whitelist_options['general'][] = 'home';
    /** etc... **/
}
```

Now I try updating this options in my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'update_forceurl' );
function update_forceurl() {
    $xsiteurl   = get_site_url();
    $find       = array( 'http://' );
    $replace    = 'https://';
    $finalurl   = str_replace( $find, $replace, $xsiteurl );

    update_option( 'siteurl', $finalurl );
    update_option( 'home', $finalurl );
}
```

Comment: please do not rant in your questions, unless the rant is relevant to th question itself. If you do not understand why your question was downvoted the right place to try to figure it out is either at the meta section of the site or at the "the loop" chat room.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default Site url settings on WORDPRESS multisite?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/295101/how-to-set-default-site-url-settings-on-wordpress-multisite)

Comment: You can't set HTTPS by assigning `on` value to the `$_SERVER` array element. `$_SERVER` is dedicated to provide the information, not to set up the server environment. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: I refresh my question, the problem maybe in contact with set_url_scheme, but I so far I have not found anything about this...

Comment: Please stop editing the question. It's impossible to help you when the question subject gets changed multiple times. When you want to ask a different question, please, start the new one.

Comment: Please don't put the answer to your question in the question itself. Below is an answer section specifically for that. For more information, [take the tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved:

Add these code to the functions.php file of your subsite's theme, immediately after the initial "

AND READ THIS, BEFORE USING:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_functions.php

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
   $xsiteurl = get_option( 'home' );
   $find = array( 'http://', 'https://' );
   if ( $find != 'http://' ) {
        $replace = '';
        $pureaddress = str_replace( $find, $replace, $xsiteurl );
        $ssladdress = 'https://' . $pureaddress . '';

        if ( $xsiteurl != $ssladdress  ) {
             update_option( 'siteurl', '' . $ssladdress . '' );
             update_option( 'home', '' . $ssladdress . '' );
        }
   }
}
```

Notes:
Originally the best it would have been the `get_option( 'siteurl' )`, that determine the "$xsiteurl", but this code deprecated, and the wordpress recommend that use it instead the `site_url()`, because "equivalent functionality", BUT THIS FALSE:
If you use the get_site_url() on a multisite, what using https on .htaccess, wp-config.php and on the network home, such as WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME, the output of `get_site_url()` will be https://subdomain.domain.com even if this subsite real (so/and default) site url and home options are: http://subdomain.domain.com. ERGO: `get_site_url()` is not nearly equal with `get_option( 'siteurl' )`...

Although your .htaccess redirect your subsite (what have http on own siteurl and home options) to https, and this will work fine, but will cause mixed content issue on your site, so than your network home have a link what shows to your subsite, your SSL will not work properly and to you need to correct this bad links in your database with example Better Search Replace plugin...

When I used `get_option( 'home' );` this gives the REAL value of the home url option unlikely `get_site_url()`.

Finally the `if ( $xsiteurl != $ssladdress  )` takes care of it that code dont running repeatedly (see in the wordpress codex link), so this safe...

The last "fly in the ointment", this code it only runs out on a site, if someone open the site (even wp admin, even the front-end)... so the new subsites default siteurl and home options they will remain http, and this code only rewrite this defaults after the code run out... (This maybe can cause mixed content problems if you creating a new subsite, and without that first open it this site's back or front-end, broadcasting posts on this from other subsites... )

postscript: I am only web designer and just now learning php, If you know something bad with this code, please write it down.